# What auto-review comments do you use?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

[AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) is an extension for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoreviewcomments/bcfoamnigomkoaaiceppbbdlembpeejc) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/se-autoreviewcomments/)* which lets you save comments to save typing the same ones over and over again.

The default ones aren't necessarily the best fit for every site, though. What comments do you use?

Note: if you're thinking of using other people's comments yourself, they also don't always work for every *user* - you might want to edit to get the right tone or just to avoid everyone sounding the same, and if you're not a moderator, some of them may not even make sense.

<sub>* There may be [a bug making the Firefox version only work on StackOverflow](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/issues/66), unfortunately.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Note: the links in these use the $SITENAME$ url placeholder, so the links don't actually work here, but if you put the same thing into AutoReviewComments it'll work fine.

---

#### [A] Question as answer

We'd love to have your question, but you've posted it as an answer instead and it needs to be in the right place - you can [post it as a question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) instead (there's an Ask Question button at the top right). Since it's currently not in the right place, I'm afraid I'll have to delete it. (We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and we stick to that format - see the [about] page.)

#### [A] Thank you answer

We're really glad we could help you out, but since we're a Q&A site not a discussion forum, we ask that you not post "thank you" as an answer but rather just upvote all the things you found helpful - that's our way of saying thank you.

#### [A] 'Me too!' answer

If you have a *new* question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://$SITEURL$/questions/ask) button - be sure to explain how it's different from this one, though! If this is exactly your question, though, these are all the answers we have for now. You can "star" the question as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

#### [A] Link-only answer

While the content you linked to might answer the question, [it’s much better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. I’ve gone ahead and edited for you! Please feel free to edit further if you think I haven’t done your answer justice.

#### [A] Comment as answer

You’ve posted this as an answer, but it doesn’t answer the question and makes more sense as a comment. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments yourself](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/comment); for now I've converted this one for you.

#### [A] OP reply answer

Please use the "Post Your Answer" button only for actual answers. To add additional information to your question, simply click the "edit" link right below it and add it right in. I've gone ahead and done that for you! Please feel free to edit further if you think I haven’t done your question justice. (You can also reply in the comments on your question.)

Comment: To be honest, I think some of these formulations are crossing that fine line between polite and ingratiating, and just don't sound sincere. The original set of comments aimed to be concise, so people who received them would (sometimes) actually read them.

Comment: @Aaronut Well, like I said, use the style you prefer. I've gotten hostile responses enough times for the tone of the original formulation and think this works better for me.

Comment: This seems to have some broken links. The two sections that should link to the [ask](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page bring up a blank page titled $SITEURL$/questions/ask. The one designed to link to the [comment privilege](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) page brings up a similar one: $SITEURL$/privileges/comment. I'd try to fix it but I don't have editing privileges here! I know this comment is off-topic so I'll delete after you've had a chance to see it. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue Those should work within the AutoReviewComments tool - they'll be replaced with the current site. (It does look like AutoReviewComments has been updated, though - I'll confirm later that everything here still works right.)

Comment: Thanks much. I know you have many more important things to do, but I like seeing how things work!

Comment: @Sue Well, I do have a real job to pay attention to sometimes, but the site isn't actually that busy, so please do keep asking things like this, it's no trouble at all.

Comment: @Sue Okay, yes - they do work right, and I added the [A] to restrict them to show up for answers only. (You can now also have auto comments separately for questions, close reasons, and edit summaries, but I only just learned that and don't have anything to add!)